# Rails change path of resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this `routes.rb`:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :students do
    collection do
      get :posters
      get :stories
    end
  end

  root "department#index"
  get "department/about"
end
```

Initially, `students` is a database where I store students information. So for each student the URL should be `students/:id`. Now I want to move it to `students/stories/:id`.

How can I do it? Thank you!

Comment: > Initially, students is a database where I store students information. 

You mean a table, right ?

Comment: Yeah I mean it is a table

Answer (score 0):

You basically need to define a `students` namespace and a `stories` resource inside it like below:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :students do
    resources :stories, only: %i[index show update destroy create] do
    end
  end
end
```

I have added all the default actions in the `only` list. You can remove the routes you don't need.